# Is there a way in Power Query to add short piece of text to every cell that contains text/numbers below a certain point?

Tags: powerquery

I have a list of items that are going to be swapped for new ones in specific stores.  In order to transpose them into a store specific list, I'd like to add "STR" to every cell that contains a store number below a certain point in the list.  That way i could differentiate them from the item numbers.

Here is an example of the table

```
|          | Swap #1| Swap #2|
|Group     | Food   | Drinks |
|Drop item | 111    |  222   |
|New Item  | 112    |  223   |
|StoreCount|  2     |   1    |
|          |  114   |   10   |
|          |  5     |        |
```

Where the stores are 114, 5, and 10.  So everything below "Store Count" could get "STR" appended to it.
I'll be able to sort them with that and then remove it so that the end result will eventually look something like:

```
|Store|Drop Item|New Item|Group |
| 114 |   111   |  112   |Food  |
| 5   |   111   |  112   |Food  |
| 10  |   222   |  223   |Drinks|
```

Comment: What we used to do is take everything from a column below the "store count" row in the first table, paste it into another sheet, then paste the drop item from that column into a new column and do the same with the "new item" and "group" so that is looked like the 2nd table.

Then we would move to the next column on table 1 and do the same until we had a list of unique swaps that would be happening in each store.

Comment: i'm assuming it may just be a matter of using "Table.transformcolumns" and "table.insert"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step",{"SWAP #1", each _ & " STR"}, each _ & " STR")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is your question now solved?

Comment: Yes.  But i couldn't accept the answer immediately.